# Using Scipy Generate and plot the Probability Density Function (PDF) of the normal distributions N[5,3²]

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, statistics

How to plot  Probability Density Function I worked out the pdf using stats.norm.rvs?

```
import scipy.stats
from scipy import stats

pdf=stats.norm.rvs(5,3**2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`stats.norm.pdf()` is the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) (pdf). For given x-value s, it calculates their probability density. The percent-point function (ppf) can help to decide which range of x-values to show.  E.g. `ppf(0.001)` would be the x-value such that there is only 0.1% probability that a value is lower.

`stats.norm.rvs()` generates one or more random samples.  Using enough samples you can create a histogram that strongly resembles the pdf. The histogram needs to be scaled down depending on the number of samples (`density=True`) to be at the same scale as the pdf.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

num_samples = 1000000
samples = stats.norm.rvs(loc=5, scale=3 ** 2, size=num_samples)
plt.hist(samples, bins=50, density=True, histtype='stepfilled', color='dodgerblue', alpha=0.3,
         label=f'histogram using\n {num_samples:,} samples')
x = np.linspace(stats.norm.ppf(0.001, loc=5, scale=3 ** 2), stats.norm.ppf(0.999, loc=5, scale=3 ** 2), 500)
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, loc=5, scale=3 ** 2), color='crimson', label='pdf')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: stats.norm.pdf]